# mex cc file in ubuntu

Tags: matlab, ubuntu, mex

I've download some code online. The makefile is like following:

```
all: cascade

cascade: cascade.cc model.cc model.h
    mex -o cascade                          \
    CXXFLAGS="\$$CXXFLAGS -O3 -march=nocona -fomit-frame-pointer"   \
    cascade.cc model.cc

clean:
    rm *.mex*
```

I use command !make to run in matlab. But it gives me the following error:

```
mex -O cascade                          \
    CXXFLAGS="\$CXXFLAGS -O3 -march=nocona -fomit-frame-pointer"    \
    cascade.cc model.cc
/bin/sh: 1: mex: not found
make: *** [cascade] Error 127
```

I go to /bin/sh of my system. There is no `mex` indeed.
What should I do to add `mex` to /bin/sh.

Thanks

Comment: you must have `mex` available on the `PATH`. Where do you have MATLAB installed? perhaps `locate mex` or [similar commands](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FindingFiles) will help.